# Getting power from iRobot Create Command Module?

Tags: ros, kinect, create-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm getting ready to follow the tutorial for [powering a Kinect off an iRobot Create](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20Kinect%20to%20an%20iRobot%20Create), and I was wondering: I have the Command Module for the Create and the [User Manual](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:HKdZu7z6de4J:www.irobot.com/filelibrary/pdfs/hrd/create/Command%2520Module%2520Manual_v2.pdf+irobot+create+command+module&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShce0GyZ31aXOZ-rWwNKAr1ERn57v0jEnVc1lJVTFZh0wqEf8bT5o3ftXWyngTMZ7OW6Smv7il2ruFrJpIxALNPjB6EHM7RE_ue1Nzii91zEgGaEgLi5HFui79_iTgHazEiCuNZ&sig=AHIEtbRV0ZwpBbBjV56v9nKHBZpHwdGnCw) shows that the DB9 connectors on the Command Module have pins for 5VDC and "Create Battery Voltage".  This leads me to two questions:

1. I need 5V power to a USB hub on the Create--does anyone know if I can get this off one of the DB9s?  And if so, what would be the mA rating?
2. Can I power the Kinect off the "Create Battery Voltage" pin on one of the DB9s?  Or is that unregulated power?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9323/getting-power-from-irobot-create-command-module?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-08**:
Just an update that using pins 12 and 25 plus a 12V regulator works like a charm with the Kinect.  I'm also using pins 14 and 10 together with a 5V regulator to power a small USB hub since my onboard laptop only has a single USB port and I am also using a Hokuyo laser scanner and an IMU.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-07**:
Thanks Murph--that's good to know!  I like the idea of hooking up to the 25-pin connector directly so I'll give that a try.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-07**:
That tutorial is incorrect about using the Serial connectors. They will not supply enough amperage and your kinect will have many transient issues as it fails to power the video cameras properly.

I'm not sure about the command module, but I used the DB25 connector that the command module plugs into directly without any issue. I used pin 12 for vin and pin 25 for ground.

Someone (who knows more than me) did say that I should be careful about it drawing the battery too low and should add an 'enable' pin to the regulator, but I have not looked into that yet, so I'll pass the warning on to you.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The manual for the Create can be found here: http://www.irobot.com/filelibrary/create/Create%20Manual_Final.pdf

1. The 5V switched output in the cargo bay is rated at only 100mA. I imagine that the command module is similar in rating.
2. You'll note that the battery voltage is about 14-15V, far too high for the Kinect. However, adding a 12V regulator as shown in the tutorial you reference will solve that problem.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-07**:
Thanks Fergs.  Yeah I found that manual and saw the 100mA rating.  So I have everything hooked up now to a 12V regulator attached to pins 12 and 25 of a DB25 connector (thanks to Murph).

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.  please tell solution.